# automatically create a record in object 2 when a new record is created in object 1

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger triggertask on book1__c (before update) {
    list<book2__c> book =new list<book2__c>();
    for(book1__c mybook:trigger.old){
        book2__c bk= new book2__c();
        bk.name=mybook.name;
         book.add(bk);
    }
             insert book;
}
```

Comment: What error/issue you are facing ?

Comment: If your requirement is simply to create a record on object2 when a new record is created in object1, then why don't you use [Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm). You should avoid using custom code as much as possible and use standard functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through [Trigger unit](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) in trailhead to understand how trigger work. If you want to insert another record on insert you need to write your trigger on after insert call as after update will not be available.

```
trigger triggertask on book1__c (after insert) {
    list<book2__c> book =new list<book2__c>();
    for(book1__c mybook:trigger.new){
        book2__c bk = new book2__c();
        bk.name=mybook.name;
         book.add(bk);
    }

    insert book;
}
```